# How to call stored procedure with multiple values in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I need to call a SQL Server stored procedure from Java. This is the stored procedure:

```
 DECLARE @t_certificate v.vt_VidaDollarsCertificates
 INSERT INTO @t_certificate VALUES(1,710335,'FFRLODOLAR',363)
 INSERT INTO @t_certificate VALUES(1,710335,'FFRLODOLAR05',363)
 INSERT INTO @t_certificate VALUES(1,710335,'FFRLODOLAR06',363)
 EXEC v.vprdl_CertificateInsert @t_certificate
```

What I do is to create a raw query and then with a PreparedStatement add the information.

I create the raw query like this:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append(
        "DECLARE @t_certificate v.vt_VidaDollarsCertificates;"
        + "INSERT @t_certificate VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
for (int i = 0; i < arrCertificates.size() - 1; ++i) {
    query.append(",(?,?,?,?) ");
}
query.append("; EXEC v.vprdl_CertificateInsert @t_certificate");
```

This is the raw query that is formed

```
DECLARE @t_certificate v.vt_VidaDollarsCertificates;INSERT @t_certificate VALUES(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ,(?,?,?,?) ; EXEC v.vprdl_CertificateInsert @t_certificate
```

Then I create the PreparedStatement.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < arrCertificates.size(); ++i) {
    preparedStmt.setInt(1, arrCertificates.get(i).getCertificateTypeID());
    preparedStmt.setInt(2, arrCertificates.get(i).getContratoID());
    preparedStmt.setString(3, arrCertificates.get(i).getFolio());
    preparedStmt.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(arrCertificates.get(i).getID()));

}
```

After that I use executeUpdate.

```
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

But it is not working, it throws an exception

> the value is not set for the parameter number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you set the wrong index to the prepapred statement because in all iteration you set the same values :

```
VALUES(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?) ,(?,?,?,?)
       1 2 3 4   1 2 3 4    1 2 3 4
```

it seems this is not correct, instead you can use :

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arrCertificates.size(); ++i) {
    preparedStmt.setInt(j++, arrCertificates.get(i).getCertificateTypeID());
    preparedStmt.setInt(j++, arrCertificates.get(i).getContratoID());
    preparedStmt.setString(j++, arrCertificates.get(i).getFolio());
    preparedStmt.setInt(j++, Integer.parseInt(arrCertificates.get(i).getID()));
}
```

---

So for 3 inputs it should gives you :

```
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?) ,(?, ?, ?, ?)
       1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8    9  10 11 12
```

Comment: you are welcome @mavi, you can make it with the new way, check my edit

Comment: Great! I like your solution